# Jupyter PDF via LaTeX - TeXLive installation incomplete

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyterhub

Context: Notebooks on a Jupyter Litlest Hub

When I want to download as ***'pdf via LaTeX'***, I get the following error ...

> ```
> nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
> Failed to run "['xelatex', './notebook.tex', '-quiet']" command:
> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
>  restricted \write18 enabled. kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
> Can't locate mktexlsr.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/tljh/user/share/tlpkg /opt/tljh/user/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /opt/tljh/user/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /opt/tljh/user/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /opt/tljh/user/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /opt/tljh/user/lib/5.26.2 .) at /opt/tljh/user/bin/mktexfmt line 23.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/tljh/user/bin/mktexfmt line 25.
> I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
> ```

To resolve missing elements, I tried `sudo -E fmtutil-sys --all`

Unfortunately, I then get the following message in the terminal.

> ```
> Can't locate mktexlsr.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/tljh/user/share/tlpkg/opt/tljh/user/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /opt/tljh/user/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /opt/tljh/user/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /opt/tljh/user/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /opt/tljh/user/lib/5.26.2 .) at /opt/tljh/user/bin/fmtutil line 23.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/tljh/user/bin/fmtutil line 25.
> ```

Furthermore, tried `sudo apt-get upgrade texlive`
and then I get the message that there were some problems, but I have no idea how to resolve this.

> ```
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  texlive-base
>  texlive-fonts-recommended
>  texlive-plain-generic
>  texlive
>  texlive-generic-recommended
>  texlive-xetex
>  texlive-latex-base
>  texlive-latex-recommended
>  texlive-latex-extra
>  texlive-pictures
>  tipa
>  cm-super
>  cm-super-minimal
> ```

Has anybody encountered these specific errors?

Is anybody using a Jupyter Litlest Hub whereby '**download pdf via LaTeX**' is working? If so, which packages were installed?

Comment: It might be a small "error" in the LaTeX. For example, for me it failed to compile $3 + \epsilon $ and gave me this error, but it worked when the trailing space was removed.